# Поставить запятую

Tags: орфография

Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении: "Сделал вид что удивился"? Если да, то куда и по какому правилу?

Comment: Перед что в 99% случаев ставится запятая, так как это самый-самый подчинительный союз. Бывает, очень редко, что не ставится, и еще бывает, когда "потомучто", тогда ставится перед потому, хотя бывает версия союза "потому, что", которую не нужно путать с *потомучто* / *потому что* (как пишут по-современному)

Comment: @
Буратино  А если так: Удивить его может что угодно. Нужна запятая?

Comment: @Sharon тут не нужна, "что" тут не союз)

Comment: @Sharon ну можно сделать так: сделал вид что - удивился...

Comment: А что же? ))  Мы-то видим слово ЧТО. А в вашем примере запятая тоже нужна, другой придумайте.

Answer (score 1):

***Сделал вид, что удивился.***

Это сложноподчиненное предложеие с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая ставится перед союзом ЧТО. Придаточное относится к существительному "вид".

Сравнить: ***Увидел, что..***.  Здесь придаточное относится к глаголу.